# Can't start Rails console in test with Spring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Without spring, I can do:

```
$ rails console test
```

And it works as expected. However, if I do

```
$ spring rails console test
```

I get the following error:

```
Loading test environment (Rails 3.2.13)
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/magic-file.rb:7:in `initialize': No such file or directory - test (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/magic-file.rb:7:in `open'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/magic-file.rb:7:in `open'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/input-method.rb:77:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/context.rb:82:in `new'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/context.rb:82:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:99:in `new'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:99:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:56:in `new'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:56:in `start'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/bundler/gems/spring-661a416d27e5/lib/spring/commands.rb:187:in `call'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/bundler/gems/spring-661a416d27e5/lib/spring/application.rb:71:in `block in serve'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/bundler/gems/spring-661a416d27e5/lib/spring/application.rb:66:in `fork'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/bundler/gems/spring-661a416d27e5/lib/spring/application.rb:66:in `serve'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/bundler/gems/spring-661a416d27e5/lib/spring/application.rb:49:in `block in run'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/bundler/gems/spring-661a416d27e5/lib/spring/application.rb:43:in `loop'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/bundler/gems/spring-661a416d27e5/lib/spring/application.rb:43:in `run'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/bundler/gems/spring-661a416d27e5/lib/spring/application.rb:37:in `start'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/bundler/gems/spring-661a416d27e5/lib/spring/application_manager.rb:96:in `block in start_child'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/bundler/gems/spring-661a416d27e5/lib/spring/application_manager.rb:83:in `fork'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/bundler/gems/spring-661a416d27e5/lib/spring/application_manager.rb:83:in `start_child'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/bundler/gems/spring-661a416d27e5/lib/spring/application_manager.rb:26:in `start'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/bundler/gems/spring-661a416d27e5/lib/spring/application_manager.rb:53:in `block in with_child'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/bundler/gems/spring-661a416d27e5/lib/spring/application_manager.rb:20:in `synchronize'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/bundler/gems/spring-661a416d27e5/lib/spring/application_manager.rb:42:in `with_child'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/bundler/gems/spring-661a416d27e5/lib/spring/application_manager.rb:61:in `run'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/bundler/gems/spring-661a416d27e5/lib/spring/server.rb:52:in `serve'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/bundler/gems/spring-661a416d27e5/lib/spring/server.rb:40:in `block in boot'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/bundler/gems/spring-661a416d27e5/lib/spring/server.rb:40:in `loop'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/bundler/gems/spring-661a416d27e5/lib/spring/server.rb:40:in `boot'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/bundler/gems/spring-661a416d27e5/lib/spring/server.rb:18:in `boot'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/bundler/gems/spring-661a416d27e5/lib/spring/client/start.rb:13:in `call'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/bundler/gems/spring-661a416d27e5/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/bundler/gems/spring-661a416d27e5/lib/spring/client.rb:23:in `run'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/bundler/gems/spring-661a416d27e5/bin/spring:5:in `<main>'
```

Here's my Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 3.2.0'

gem 'devise', '~> 2.2.0'
gem 'has_scope'
gem 'high_voltage'
gem 'inherited_resources'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'ransack'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'validates_existence'
gem 'validates_timeliness'

# deployment process management
gem 'foreman'
gem 'thin'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '< 2.0'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-bundler'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.2.0'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.10'
  # TODO: Look for spring gem release '> 0.0.8'
  # currently using locally installed gem@master, not repeatable!
  # cd `bundle show spring` && gem build spring.gemspec && gem install spring-0.0.8.gem
  gem 'spring', :github => 'jonleighton/spring'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'growl'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'oj' # TODO: Remove after multi-json '1.7.5'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'simplecov', :require => false
end
```

And my Gemfile.lock:

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/jonleighton/spring.git
  revision: 661a416d27e554bf1c839a2cd35b8a87e6317175
  specs:
    spring (0.0.8)

GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.13)
      actionpack (= 3.2.13)
      mail (~> 2.5.3)
    actionpack (3.2.13)
      activemodel (= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.4.5)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.2.1)
    activemodel (3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.13)
      activemodel (= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.13)
      activemodel (= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
    activesupport (3.2.13)
      i18n (= 0.6.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    addressable (2.3.4)
    arel (3.0.2)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
    bootstrap-sass (2.3.1.0)
      sass (~> 3.2)
    builder (3.0.4)
    capybara (2.1.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (~> 2.0)
    coderay (1.0.9)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
    daemons (1.1.9)
    devise (2.2.3)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (~> 3.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.1)
    diff-lcs (1.2.4)
    dotenv (0.7.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (1.0.3)
    execjs (1.4.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    factory_girl (4.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.2.1)
      factory_girl (~> 4.2.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    ffi (1.8.1)
    foreman (0.63.0)
      dotenv (>= 0.7)
      thor (>= 0.13.6)
    formatador (0.2.4)
    growl (1.0.3)
    guard (1.8.0)
      formatador (>= 0.2.4)
      listen (>= 1.0.0)
      lumberjack (>= 1.0.2)
      pry (>= 0.9.10)
      thor (>= 0.14.6)
    guard-bundler (1.0.0)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      guard (~> 1.1)
    guard-rspec (2.6.0)
      guard (>= 1.8)
      rspec (~> 2.13)
    has_scope (0.5.1)
    high_voltage (1.2.2)
    hike (1.2.2)
    i18n (0.6.1)
    inherited_resources (1.4.0)
      has_scope (~> 0.5.0)
      responders (~> 0.9)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (2.2.1)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.0)
    kaminari (0.14.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    launchy (2.3.0)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
    listen (1.1.4)
      rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.3)
      rb-inotify (>= 0.9)
      rb-kqueue (>= 0.2)
    lumberjack (1.0.3)
    mail (2.5.3)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    method_source (0.8.1)
    mime-types (1.23)
    multi_json (1.7.4)
    nokogiri (1.5.9)
    oj (2.0.14)
    orm_adapter (0.4.0)
    pg (0.15.1)
    polyamorous (0.5.0)
      activerecord (~> 3.0)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    pry (0.9.12.1)
      coderay (~> 1.0.5)
      method_source (~> 0.8)
      slop (~> 3.4)
    rack (1.4.5)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-ssl (1.3.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.13)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.13)
      actionpack (= 3.2.13)
      activerecord (= 3.2.13)
      activeresource (= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.13)
    railties (3.2.13)
      actionpack (= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)
    rake (10.0.4)
    ransack (0.7.2)
      actionpack (~> 3.0)
      activerecord (~> 3.0)
      polyamorous (~> 0.5.0)
    rb-fsevent (0.9.3)
    rb-inotify (0.9.0)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
    rb-kqueue (0.2.0)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    responders (0.9.3)
      railties (~> 3.1)
    rspec (2.13.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.13.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.13.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.13.0)
    rspec-core (2.13.1)
    rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3, < 2.0)
    rspec-mocks (2.13.1)
    rspec-rails (2.13.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.13.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.13.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.13.0)
    sass (3.2.8)
    sass-rails (3.2.6)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    shoulda-matchers (2.1.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    simple_form (2.1.0)
      actionpack (~> 3.0)
      activemodel (~> 3.0)
    simplecov (0.7.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      simplecov-html (~> 0.7.1)
    simplecov-html (0.7.1)
    slop (3.4.4)
    sprockets (2.2.2)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.7)
    thin (1.5.1)
      daemons (>= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.6)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    thor (0.18.1)
    tilt (1.3.7)
    timeliness (0.3.7)
    treetop (1.4.12)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.37)
    uglifier (1.3.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    validates_existence (0.8.0)
    validates_timeliness (3.0.14)
      timeliness (~> 0.3.6)
    warden (1.2.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    xpath (2.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  bootstrap-sass (~> 2.3.1)
  capybara
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1)
  devise (~> 2.2.0)
  factory_girl_rails (~> 4.2.0)
  foreman
  growl
  guard
  guard-bundler
  guard-rspec
  has_scope
  high_voltage
  inherited_resources
  jquery-rails
  kaminari
  launchy
  oj
  pg
  rails (~> 3.2.0)
  ransack
  rspec-rails (~> 2.10)
  sass-rails (~> 3.2.3)
  shoulda-matchers
  simple_form
  simplecov
  spring!
  sqlite3
  thin
  uglifier (< 2.0)
  validates_existence
  validates_timeliness
```

I am using rbenv and rbenv-gemset:

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
```

Spring seems to work fine otherwise... I'm not really sure what's going on here. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

I tried the suggestion below and got a different error condition.

```
$ spring rails console [test]
You did not specify how you would like Rails to report deprecation notices for your [test] environment, please set config.active_support.deprecation to :log, :notify or :stderr at config/environments/[test].rb
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:176:in `split': bad URI(is not URI?): [test] (URI::InvalidURIError)
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:211:in `parse'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:747:in `parse'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:61:in `connection_url_to_hash'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:36:in `block in resolve_string_connection'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:35:in `fetch'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:35:in `resolve_string_connection'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:25:in `spec'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:130:in `establish_connection'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `block in on_load'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `each'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `on_load'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:74:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/jcarlson/Projects/prohub/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/application.rb:31:in `start'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/application_manager.rb:96:in `block in start_child'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/application_manager.rb:83:in `fork'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/application_manager.rb:83:in `start_child'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/application_manager.rb:26:in `start'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/application_manager.rb:53:in `block in with_child'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/application_manager.rb:20:in `synchronize'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/application_manager.rb:42:in `with_child'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/application_manager.rb:61:in `run'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/server.rb:52:in `serve'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/server.rb:40:in `block in boot'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/server.rb:40:in `loop'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/server.rb:40:in `boot'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/server.rb:18:in `boot'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/client/start.rb:13:in `call'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/client.rb:23:in `run'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/spring-0.0.8/bin/spring:5:in `<main>'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/application_manager.rb:66:in `run': undefined method `chomp' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/server.rb:52:in `serve'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/server.rb:40:in `block in boot'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/server.rb:40:in `loop'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/server.rb:40:in `boot'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/server.rb:18:in `boot'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/client/start.rb:13:in `call'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/spring-0.0.8/lib/spring/client.rb:23:in `run'
    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/gemsets/prohub/gems/spring-0.0.8/bin/spring:5:in `<main>'
```